# Using AZCopy to download blobs from all containers at one time

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azcopy

I need to copy all containers and blobs from an Azure storage account.  I've figured out how to download one container at a time, but this is quite tedious.  I would like to download all of them at one time.

Anyone out there have information on this?

Thanks,

James

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, we couldn't use azcopy to copy all the container's file to local at one time.

As you say, we could download one container to local at one time.

Here is a work around:

We could firstly list all the container by using command-line tool(e.g powershell)(Get-AzureStorageContainer), then use foreach to download the file to local.

The powershell script like this:

```
$SourceStorageAccountName = "<SourceStorageAccountName>"
$SourceStorageKey = Get-AzureStorageKey -StorageAccountName $SourceStorageAccountName
$StorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SourceStorageKey.StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $SourceStorageKey.Primary
$containers = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $StorageContext

foreach ($c in $containers) {
    "Transfer container " + $c.Name
    $cmd = "C:\'Program Files (x86)'\'Microsoft SDKs'\Azure\AzCopy\AzCopy.exe /Source:" + $c.CloudBlobContainer.Uri.AbsoluteUri + " /Dest: +"youfile path"

    Invoke-Expression $cmd
}
```